# I am preparing a music app and how to call a function from Song.java to SongDisplay.java

Tags: java, android

I've created functions in Song.java and I am unable to call `getSinger()` and `getTitle()` from Song and `getmImageId()` from Song and I have MainActivity in which I have created the intent to start a SongDisplay activity.

So how do I display duration of a song in minutes for seekBar.

**Song.java**

```
public class Song {
    private String mTitle;
    private String mDuration;
    private String mSinger;
    private int mImageId;

    public Song(String title, String duration, String singer,int imageId) {
        mTitle = title;
        mDuration = duration;
        mSinger = singer;
        mImageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return mDuration;
    }

    public String getSinger() { return mSinger;  }

    public int getmImageId() {
        return mImageId;
    }
}
```

**SongDisplay.java**

```
public class SongDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
     ImageView imageDisplay;
     TextView singerText;
     TextView songName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
         imageDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_display);

        singerText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.singer_text);
        singerText.setText(String .valueOf(getSinger()));

        songName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since they are not static methods (not functions), you'll need to call them through an instance of the class Song. (and no, you don't want to make them static)

Comment: add the code how you are calling getSinger method

Comment: You need to have instance of that class "Song"

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be an instance of the `Song` class created using the new operator and the constructor.  This will allow you to  invoke the methods on the class to retrieve the values stored in the fields via their accessors.  The values retrieved would be specific to that particular instances of the class.  If you required another song, it would be a separate instance of the class.

For Example:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Instance created here
        Song song = new Song("Imagine", "3:14", "Beatles", 1);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
         imageDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_display);

        singerText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.singer_text);

        //method invoked on instance here
        singerText.setText(song.getSinger());

        songName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_text);

    }
```

If you are interested in learning more, I covered class instances in this [lesson](http://www.tothought.com/post/25) found on my personal blog.

Comment: String.valueOf(song.getSinger()) ? why trying to parse a String into a String?